# UITableViewCell with images in different dimensions

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to use my *ReusableCell* for cells with images in different dimensions. The images are put inside a 220x150 black box with with scaling `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NewsItem *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.imageUrl]];
    [cell.imageView setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
    [cell.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    CGRect imageViewFrame = cell.imageView.frame;
    imageViewFrame.size.width = 220;
    imageViewFrame.size.height = 150
    [cell.imageView setFrame:imageViewFrame];

    [cell.textLabel setText:item.title];

    return cell;
}
```

The above code results in a layout like below and the images are sometimes changing when scrolling in the table view.

[image: UITableView with images]

Instead of this unstructured layout, I would like the images to be aligned like this:

[image: Images in a black box]

What am I doing wrong with this *ReusableCell*?

**EDIT1:**

I'm trying to create an imageView and add this imageView as a superview to cell.contentView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NewsItem *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImagePlaceholderThumb"]; //220x150

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:placeholderImage];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.imageUrl]];
    [imageView setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    CGRect imageViewFrame = imageView.frame;
    imageViewFrame.size.width = placeholderImage.size.width;
    imageViewFrame.size.height = placeholderImage.size.height;
    [imageView setFrame:imageViewFrame];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    [cell.textLabel setText:item.title];

    return cell;
}
```

The above code results in the following:

[image: UIImageView in superview]

It is like some of the images are visible in two cells. It seems that they are not keeping the size I've set in the *imageViewFrame*. Do you know why?

Comment: What you are looking for is called letter boxing and AFAIK that is something UIKit will not do for you unless you do it yourself.

Comment: So, how can I do this myself?

Comment: See the comment to my own answer. Also, as an aside, the way you are creating the UIImageView and loading it's data is happening EVERY time the cell becomes visible from off screen. You might see some sketchy scrolling. I would two things differently: 0) load the image data asynchronously and cache it with something like EGOImageView, 1) Generally, you want to create a cell's subviews when you create the cell, you just want to change the content of the subviews after //Configure the cell...

Comment: See my Answer Edit for an example of point 1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<s>A quick fix would be using content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. Images will be stretched in one or both dimensions to fill up the whole image view bounds.</s>

You really need subclassing `UITableViewCell` to do this right.

Thre is a *lazy* solution adding a new `UIImageView` and using a spacer, as Keller told you in his answer (feel free to accept his answer, this is just the missing code).

Extract of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
...
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell #%i", indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer.png"]; /* spacer is 64 x 44 */
/* image view width should be ~ 64 px, otherwise it will overlap the text */
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={64, tableView.rowHeight}}];
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"waterfall.png"];
        break;
    /* etc... */
}
if (indexPath.row < 3) {
    /* add black bg to cell w/ images */
    iv.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
iv.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
...
```

The table will look like this:
[image: aspect fit]

You need to set the placeholder (`spacer.png` above) in the existing cell image view. It will push the text label to the right.

You can use aspect fill and remove the background color bit:

```
iv.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

The table will look wrong because the image is drawn outsite the bounds:

[image: aspect fill without clipping]

Just clip to bounds to get a better result:

```
iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

[image: aspect fill]

Comment: Sorry, but that is now a solution for me. I need the images to keep their ratio.

Comment: The ratio is kept, only whole image won't be visible. Anyway, it's not as easy as I said. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UIImageView subview for each cell and it to the contentView. Each UIImageView contains an image with a consistent frame but with option `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. Then just Set the background color of the UIImageView to black.

I just confirmed this works, but you need to also create a placeholder spacer image to make sure the textLabel moves out of the way. Just make it the same dimensions of your image (with the letter boxing).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //spacer
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

    //imageview
    UIImageView *thumbnail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 44)];
    thumbnail.tag = kThumbTag;
    thumbnail.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbnail];
  }

  // Configure the cell...

  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row];

  cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 44);

  UIImageView *thumb = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kThumbTag];
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [thumb setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
  } else {
    [thumb setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Obviously, this example isn't lazy loading the images (I didn't realize you were loading them from a URL). For that, I would use a subclass with [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/commits/master/EGOImageView) or something of the like.

Comment: I notice your placeholder image has a frame size of 220 x 150 - is 150px really the height you want for your cell? If so, you just need to set cell.rowHeight (in your nib or in viewDidLoad). Otherwise, just make sure your placeholder image is the correct frame size you're looking for or resize its frame.

Comment: Actually, you could also just use the UITableView delegate method 'indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath'